# Normal lying inside the mirror surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, reflection, geometric-optics

[image]

In the problem above what does the question means by given normal lying inside the mirror surface?

Is it has something to do that they have i and j components same.

I also wanted to know what does the  question is trying to bring out by this certain thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

inside normal does NOT say inside the mirror. It ist the normal pointing to the mirror.

Comment: Yeah, but what does it mean mathematically?

Comment: the text tells how to compute the reflected direction compared to the incoming direction and the normal on the mirror